# QT QML not resizing dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I am fairly new to QT and would need some help with qml dynamic resizing. I am using Visual Studio with QT plugin, MSVC 2017 compiler.

Here is my qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Rectangle
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    // or width/height here

    Rectangle
    {
       anchors.fill: parent
       color: "blue"
    }
}
```

My custom QQuickWidget:

```
customWidget::customWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    this->setParent(parent);
    this->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), parent->size())); //this is for debugging only
    this->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView); 
    this->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qmlpath"));
}
```

Widget Initialization

```
    myWidget = new customWidget(ui.widgetArea); // widgetArea is an empty QWidget from the Qt Designer
    qDebug() << myWidget->errors();

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(myWidget);
    ui.widgetArea->setLayout(layout);
```

I have tried other suggestions like enclosing the rectangles in a grid layout for example and use "layout.fillWidth: true" etc. 
Everything gives me a blank space (widget size of 0, 0) instead of a blue rectangle, unless I define a fixed width and height for it. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: provide a [mre], share the .ui

Comment: Should I upload the minimal example as zip file here?

Comment: No, SO does not allow uploading files except images, you must place everything as text.

Comment: Then, this is pretty much the minimal example. I didn't do much do the custom widget.

Comment: It is a minimal example but not reproducible (I recommend you read the link). The idea is that anybody copy your code and can reproduce your problem to be able to analyze where your problem is. If it is not, it is difficult to know where the problem is. My recommendation is that you copy your project and remove everything that is not relevant with respect to the characteristic with which you have problems and that will be an MRE. I am arguing a lot with you and I do not get what I ask so if there is nothing relevant I will continue my way.